# Bayesian terminology for experiments

Tags: bayesian, experiment-design, bayesian-optimization

I am learning about bayesian experimental design and confused about the "Bayesian" terminology. Multi-armed bandits are normally in the syllabus of bayesian experiments. But there are techniques like Thompson sampling which uses bayesian optimisation and there are also non-bayesian bandit algorithms.

So my question is:

1. Can experiments conducted using epsilon greedy bandit algorithms called bayesian experiment?
2. Is bayesian optimisation different from bayesian experimental design?

Answer (score 1):

The "Bayesian" in Bayesian optimization stems from the Bayesian updating of our beliefs about the shape of the function we are optimizing.

Imagine we want to minimize $f(x) \colon R^D \to R$.  We start with prior beliefs about the shape of $f$, let's call it $\hat{f}_0$. Then, we evaluate the target function at some point, say $x_1 \in R^D$. Now, we have learned about the value $f(x_1)$. With this new information, we update our beliefs about $\hat{f}_0$ via Bayes rule. We have new beliefs, $\hat{f}_1$, and we repeat.

Note that I said "we evaluate the target function at some point $x_1$". But the question is which point to choose? The study of various strategies of choosing these points is known as "Bayesian experimental design." Why Bayesian? Because based on the prior, $\hat{f}$.

Comment: Does this mean multi-armed bandit experiments which just uses epsilon-greedy approach wouldnt come under bayesian experimental design?

Comment: @user2715182 yes, I'd say so.